# Catch Spring data exeptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I try persist list of entities:

```
for (Charge charge : charges) {
      try {
        Charge savedCharge = saveCharge(charge);
      }catch (DataAccessException e){
        log.error(e.getMessage());
      }
    }

public Charge saveCharge(Charge charge){
    return chargesRepository.save(charge);
  }
```

Sometimes I get exeptions:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: ORA-00001: the limitation of uniqueness has been violated
```

and I need catch this exeption. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You catch it as any Exception. However I suggest you to rather catch the [`DataIntegrityViolationException`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/dao/DataIntegrityViolationException.html) from Spring framework because Spring already translates SQL exceptions to the more specific ones :

```
try {
    Charge savedCharge = saveCharge(charge);
} catch (DataIntegrityViolationException e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage());
    // more error handling actions
} // more catch clauses
```